# Kindly how can I write an openscad code to create a customizable stachable cylindrical vertical tower

Tags: openscad

I need help with writing the correct openSCAD code for a vertical planter that is stackable and customizable

I want the code that will help me create the stackable planter. i an new to open scad and can only create basic shapes like cylinder but i want to be able to create cylindrical planters that will have holes on them like a tower garden and be stackable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a lot with `difference()` and `translate()`, will need to see some code to know what you are trying to achieve, but here's a simple example:

```
difference(){
    cylinder(100, 70, 80);
    
    translate([0,0,10]) cylinder(100, 70-10, 80-10);
    
    for(i=[0:45:360])
        translate([0,0,50])
        rotate([0,60,i])
        translate([20,0,0])
        cylinder(200, 10, 10);
}
```

[image]